# A potential method invoking after a POST (basically Ajaxical) request finishes

Tags: jsf, primefaces

While performing CRUD operations using JSF/PrimeFaces, a common method that resets managed bean fields/properties is generally needed which is to be invoked basically after one such operation is successfully completed so that the fields in the backing bean are reset to their initial (default) value.

Imaginary code :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean extends LazyDataModel<Entity> implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private Service service; // EJB.

    // Holds a list of selected rows in a <p:dataTable>.
    private List<Entity> selectedValues; // Getter & setter.

    private String someField; // Getter & setter.
    // Other fields depending upon the business requirement.

    public Bean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        // Do something.
    }

    @Override
    public List<Entity> load(int first, int pageSize, List<SortMeta> multiSortMeta, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        setRowCount(service.rowCount());
        // Other complex logic as and when required.
        return service.getList(first, pageSize, map, filters); // Returns a List<Entity>.
    }

    // Resets fields to their default value.
    public void reset() {
        someField = null;
        selectedValues = null;
        // Reset other fields to their default value.
    }

    // Add (insert submitted values to the database).
    // This method is basically bound to an action(Listener) of <p:commandButton>.
    public void submit() {
        if (service.insert(someField)) {
            // Add a FacesMessge to indicate a success.
            reset(); // Calling reset.
        } else {
            // Add a FacesMessge to indicate a failure.
        }
    }

    // Update the database using submitted values.
    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        if (event.getObject() instanceof Entity) {
            Entity entity = (Entity) event.getObject();
            Entity newEntity = service.update(entity);

            if (newEntity != null) {
                // Update the model.
                // Other things like adding a FacesMessage to indicate a success.
            } else {
                // Add a FacesMessage to warn against the null entity returned by the service layer.
            }
        } else {
            // Add a FacesMessage to indicate a failure.
        }

        reset(); // Finally reset the fields to their initial/default value.
    }

    // Similarly, performing the delete operation also requires to call the reset() method.
}
```

The `submit()` method performing "insert" is basically associated with JSF/PrimeFaces command components like `<p/h:commandButton>` or `<p/h:commandLink>`. Such as.

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.someField}"/>

<p:commandButton value="Submit"
                 actionListener="#{bean.submit}"
                 oncomplete="if(args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) {updateTable();}"/>

<!-- Updating a p:dataTable in question after the above p:commandButton completes. -->
<p:remoteCommand name="updateTable" update="dataTable" process="@this"/>
```

The following AJAX events associated with a `<p:dataTable>` also require to call the `reset()` method.

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit"
        onstart="..."
        oncomplete="..."
        update="..."
        listener="#{bean.onRowEdit}"/>

<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
        onstart="..."
        oncomplete="..."
        update="..."
        listener="#{bean.reset}"/>

<p:ajax event="page"
        onstart="..."
        oncomplete="..."
        update="..."
        listener="#{bean.reset}"/>

<p:ajax event="sort"
        onstart="..."
        oncomplete="..."
        update="..."
        listener="#{bean.reset}"/>

<p:ajax event="filter"
        onstart="..."
        oncomplete="..."
        update="..."
        listener="#{bean.reset}"/>
```

As can be seen, the `reset()` method needs to be memorized carefully as it is invoked from several places. The way is somewhat difficult to maintain.

Does there exist a way to invoke such a common method automatically after each POST request performing one of the CRUD operations has finished its job successfully?

Comment: Just to be sure, you're aware that you can specify multiple values in `event` attribute? Like so: `<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel page sort filter" ...>`. It seems to me that all other attributes are also identical.

Comment: Yes the rest of the attributes are identical (though `reset()` needs to be invoked manually from the backing bean while inserting, deleting. I suppose to exclude those calls too, if possible).

Comment: Just to be sure,is it *after* each post request of an event or *on* each post request of an event? It seems to be the latter now, right?

Comment: @Kukeltje : It is former i.e. "*after*".

Comment: After, for me, is in the oncomplete. On is in the listener, so I'm confused as how to investigate the PF internals for a possible solution. Or do you mean after calling a normal listener, the reset should be called like in the java code. I'm confused by the reset being called in the java code and theajax listener. Can you elaborate or inmprove question

Comment: @Kukeltje: I think the concrete technical requirement can best be summarized as follows: "Invoke a method during afterphase of INVOKE_APPLICATION on every postback which processes the given component", whereby in this particular case the component of interest is the `<p:dataTable>` and the method of interest is the `#{bean.reset}`.

Comment: @Kukeltje : In a nutshell, the `reset()` method should be invoked after any of insert, update or delete is performed so that managed bean properties can be reset to their initial value. This is done by manually invoking that method from several places as shown in the question. I expect that there should exist some way to schedule this task automatically as can be done in some action based frameworks like Struts 2.

Comment: BalusC talks about the component events, ALL of them including page events, you talk about business actions, but in the ajax calls it is like BalusC states. My solution would be to create a base class that handles the real ajax events and delegates to methods that a controller should implement and after each method call `reset()` from the base class.

Comment: I sitll fail to see how creating a base class and doing some small refactoring cannot solve this. You already have most of it in the bean in your question above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSF doesn't have any tag for this.

Ideally, you'd like to have something like a `<f:event type="postInvokeAction" listener="#{bean.reset}">` directly attached to the `<p:dataTable>`. But that event doesn't exist in JSF 2.2. OmniFaces has one, but it's only supported on `UIViewRoot`, `UIForm`, `UIInput` and `UICommand`.

The [`<f:phaseListener>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/phaseListener.html) comes close, but it gets attached to `UIViewRoot` directly, even though you place it inside `<p:dataTable>`. And, it requires a whole `PhaseListener` implementation.

The [`<f:view afterPhase>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/f/view.html) seems your best bet. You only need some additional checking on the phase ID and the source component.

```
<p:dataTable binding="#{table}" ...>
    <f:view afterPhase="#{bean.reset(table)}" />
    <p:ajax ... />
    <p:ajax ... />
    <p:ajax ... />
    <p:ajax ... />
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

```
public void reset(UIData table) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() != PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION) {
        return;
    }

    String source = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("javax.faces.source");

    if (!table.getClientId(context).equals(source)) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset logic here.
    // ...
}
```

*(`binding` could if necessary be replaced by a hardcoded table client ID)*

---

I understand that this is awkward. So, for the upcoming [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) 2.2 I have [altered](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/d364daff7f4bb69bc78eb7030610e3a77e412fbb) the existing [`InvokeActionEventListener`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/InvokeActionEventListener) to support this use case too. It now supports being attached on any `UIComponent`.

```
<p:dataTable ...>
    <f:event type="postInvokeAction" listener="#{bean.reset}" />
    <p:ajax ... />
    <p:ajax ... />
    <p:ajax ... />
    <p:ajax ... />
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

```
public void reset() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Although it is a nice solution, I personnaly I don't think this should be in the UI layer. But I might not have the knowledge to see why it better should be... So I please enlighten me... never to young^H^H^H^H^Hold to learn

Comment: You can also do it without any tags in the view, but then you'd need to hardcode some view-specific stuff (IDs and such) in the bean/listener. That's less nice. Tags in the view is more declarative and the controller/model knows less about the view that way. That's always better :)

Comment: That is not what I meant. I agree that the controller/model should know as little as needed (none?) about the view. I was rather talking about doing it in a 'base controller' Every self respecting developer that uses the PrimeFaces LazyDataModel should have one... (if you have multiple entities...). I'll try to create an 'answer' over the weekend to explain (or make a blog out of it)

Comment: Is it available in the current OmniFaces 2.2-SNAPSHOT?